# Objective-C version of a custom UIActivityType

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity, ios-sharesheet

In swift, this is quite simple. For example, if I want to add a custom Pinterest UIActivityType:

```
extension UIActivityType {
    static let postToPinterest = UIActivityType(rawValue: "pinterest.ShareExtension")
}
```

This is all I have to do. However, I'm a bit confused on how to do this in objective-c. I'm thinking something like this but I'm not quite sure.

```
static UIActivityType UIActivityTypePostToPinterest = @"myApp.pinterest.ShareExtension";
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective C, `UIActivityType` is just another name for `NSString`, so you can declare it as follows:

```
// in header file
FOUNDATION_EXPORT static NSString * const UIActivityTypePostToPinterest;

// in implementation file
FOUNDATION_EXPORT static NSString * const UIActivityTypePostToPinterest = @"myApp.pinterest.ShareExtension";
```

Although, since Objective C isn't namespaced you should use your own prefix (like `JNCActivityTypePostToPinterest` instead of `UI`, which is reserved by Apple).